# Defining max/min stats from nested JSON data in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I'd like to preface this with I'm new to python (and not traditionally a programmer) so all suggestions to clean up any of the code (even not related to the below problem) are entirely welcome. I've been stuck on this for a couple of days now so I figured I'd give it a shot here.

I have a script that calls a RESTful API via requests package, parses returned JSON data via JSON package, assigns data to variables and then writes to a csv file via csv package (which is later via vba script written to an excel file.) This all seems to work fine, but currently its writing individual data points to excel and while I'd like to keep doing that, I'd also like to calculate summary statistics for that data (min, max, average, standard deviation, etc) in python before writing to a separate CSV output file.

I would imagine the correct way to do this is to write those saved variables (initially from JSON) to a nested dictionary/list and then use max/min functions etc. on the correct list, but I'm having trouble constructing the nested dictionaries dynamically.

To be clear, each data point in the jData['ProductActivity'] node is a separate transaction. I'm trying to build a dictionary that logically looks like:

```
[prodsize1]:
    'bid':
       [bid1]
       [bid2]
    'ask':
       [ask1]
       [ask2]
    'trade':
       [trade1]
       [trade2]
[prodsize2]:
    'bid':
       [bid1]
       [bid2]
    'ask':
       [ask1]
       [ask2]
    'trade':
       [trade1]
       [trade2]
```

Where [prodSize] key and [bid][trade] & [ask] value lists are all being added dynamically off of the jData.

code:

```py
state_dict = {"trade": "3", "bid": "2", "ask": "1"}

market_activity = {}
bid_list = []
ask_list = []
trade_list = []


def get_hist(side):
    state = state_dict.get(side)

jData = json.loads(myResponse.content)

        page_length = len(jData['ProductActivity'])

        for i in range (0, page_length):
            chainId = jData['ProductActivity'][i]['chainId']
            skuUuid = jData['ProductActivity'][i]['skuUuid']
            createdAt = jData['ProductActivity'][i]['createdAt']
            prodSize = float(jData['ProductActivity'][i]['prodSize'])
            amount = float(jData['ProductActivity'][i]['amount'])
            localAmount = float(jData['ProductActivity'][i]['localAmount'])
            localCurrency = jData['ProductActivity'][i]['localCurrency']
            productId = jData['ProductActivity'][i]['productId']
            customerId = jData['ProductActivity'][i]['customerId']
            if "frequency" in jData['ProductActivity'][i]:
                frequency = jData['ProductActivity'][i]['frequency']
            else:
                frequency = 1
            csv_writer.writerow([chainId, skuUuid, createdAt, styleId, name, target_product, side, prodSize, amount, localAmount,
                                 frequency, localCurrency, productId, customerId])
            if side == 'bid':
                market_activity[prodSize] = {'bid': bid_list.append(amount)}
            elif side == 'ask':
                market_activity[prodSize] = {'ask': ask_list.append(amount)}
            elif side == 'trade':
                market_activity[prodSize] = {'trade': trade_list.append(amount)}

    myResponse.raise_for_status()

get_hist(side="trade")
get_hist(side="bid")
get_hist(side="ask")


available_sizes = []


for key in market_activity.keys():
    available_sizes.append(key)

summary_stats={'max_bid': '','min_ask': '','avg_trade': ''}

def generate_summary_stats:
    for size in available_shoe_sizes:
        summary_stats[size].update(max(market_info[size]['bid']))
        summary_stats[size].update(min(market_info[size]['ask']))
        #add in rest of stats

generate_summary_stats()

data_to_file.close()
```

I think I may need to add new keys separately and then append the lists stored as values. I also fear that the way I have it written will write over 'state' (bid, ask, trade) values instead of add to each list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to understand what you're expecting to get without an example.  Can you post a sample of what your JSON data looks like, and how you ultimately want the `market_activity` dictionary to look? As for overwriting, notice that `market_activity[prodSize] = {'bid': bid_list.append(amount)}` for example tries to assign a new value to `market_activity[prodSize]` on each run.  Maybe you want something more like `market_activity[prodSize]['bid'].append(amount)` here.  Though you'll have to set the initial `{'bid': []}` empty list before you can "append" anything to it.

Also, since you asked for some general Python coding suggestions:

- `market_activity.keys()` already returns a list, so you should be able to just replace `for size in available_shoe_sizes:` with `for size in market_activity.keys():`, and forget about making the `available_shoe_sizes` list completely
- Since "side" is the only input variable in your `get_hist()`
  function, you can just call the function as `get_hist("trade")` for
  example.  In general, the order of the parameters you pass in just has to match
  up with the order they're defined.
- I'm not sure where `market_info[]` comes from.  Is that supposed to be `market_activity`?
- In general, definitions (functions) should be put near the top of your code, instead of being defined in between other commands you're running.
- Likewise, `generate_summary_stats` should have the parameters passed through it, instead of having them be global.  Then return the value you want, which is probably the dictionary `summary_stats`.  So something more like this:

.

```
def generate_summary_stats(sizes):

    summary_stats={'max_bid': '','min_ask': '','avg_trade': ''}

    for size in sizes:
         ## Here's the loop where you'd insert your code
         ## for updating summary_stats properly.
    return summary_stats


# Getting the stats, outside of your function.
stats = generate_summary_stats(market_activity)
```